# Code snippet from R to Python for Panda dataframe graph plot

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am working with a panda data frame object. Till now I have  uploaded and processed a data frame which looks like below:
[image: Panda Dataframe]

The next step is I have to plot a graph with this data frame which will look like this
[image: Graph]

I have came across a R code snippet which will be helpfull in creating x-axis and y-axis for this graph

```
d_ends <- 
yearly_top %>% 
group_by(tag) %>% 
slice(n()) %>% 
pull(fraction)

d_ends[1] <- 0.053
d_ends[6] <- 0.024

d_labels <- 
yearly_top %>% 
group_by(tag) %>% 
slice(n()) %>% 
pull(tag)
```

I am trying to convert this in Python. Any idea would really be great

Comment: Hi newuser, If my answer works can you accept/upvote it? Next time when you ask a question on SO can you also share a real example of your data instead of a photo. This will help others greatly when trying to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [seaborns lineplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html). It's a great package for this kind of plotting:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.lineplot(data=yearly_top, x='year', y='fraction', hue='tag')
```

Comment: Each technology labels needs to be at the end of the bar lines, outside the graph area if possible